# Setting up emacs with rosemacs

Tags: ros, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the [information](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosemacs#Installation) for installing rosemacs but this has presented me with some problems.  For starters, I didn't have a .emacs file so I created one from scratch (not sure if that's what is supposed to be done).  I tried editing this file in both ways described but I keep getting errors.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/usr/.emacs':
File error: Cannot open load file, rosemacs
To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I did exactly that, opening emacs in debug mode through the command line:

```
$emacs --debug-init
```

This yields the following in the scratch area once emacs is open:

```
͂͂͂
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Opening directory" "permission denied" "/home/usr/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/")
 directory-files("~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/" nil "\\`\\.saves-" t)
 (and auto-save-list-file-prefix (file-directory-p (file-name-directory auto-save-list-file-prefix)) (directory-files (file-name-directory auto-save-list-file-prefix) nil (concat "\\`" ...) t))
  delete-process(#)
  (progn (message "Cancelling existing rostopic tracker") (delete-process old-proc))
  (if old-proc (progn (message "Cancelling existing rostopic tracker") (delete-process old-proc)))
  (when old-proc (message "Cancelling existing rostopic tracker") (delete-process old-proc))
  (let ((old-proc ...)) (when old-proc (message "Cancelling existing rostopic tracker") (delete-process old-proc)))
  (let ((name "*rostopic-tracker*")) (let (...) (when old-proc ... ...)) (when (> interval 0) (let ... ... ...)))
  rosemacs/track-topics(8)
  invoke-rosemacs()
  (progn (add-to-list (quote load-path) checked-result) (require (quote rosemacs)) (invoke-rosemacs))
  (progn (progn (add-to-list ... checked-result) (require ...) (invoke-rosemacs)))
  (if checked-result (progn (progn ... ... ...)))
  (when checked-result (progn (add-to-list ... checked-result) (require ...) (invoke-rosemacs)))
  (let* ((result ...) (checked-result ...)) (when checked-result (progn ... ... ...)))
  eval-buffer(# nil "/home/usr/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 517
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/usr/.emacs" "/home/usr/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
```

If anyone has an idea as to what might be going on please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12860/setting-up-emacs-with-rosemacs/) by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-02-02**:
Could you post the relevant part of your .emacs as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ho! Apparently you don't have the permission to browse this directory:

```
(file-error "Opening directory" "permission denied" "/home/usr/.emacs.d/auto-save-list/")
```

This can be solved by running:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /home/usr/.emacs.d
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on 2012-02-02**:
I didn't see an option for this.  Is it the "mark answer as favorite" (checkmark) option?  If so, I just did that.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-02-02**:
Happy to help :) You should probably select this as the correct answer then.

**Comment by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on 2012-02-02**:
BINGO!!  Thanks Ugo, that solved it!  I had a feeling it would be something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `.emacs` file is a per-user configuration file; it should be in `/home/whatever`, not in `/usr`, which is for system libraries and shared data.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on 2012-02-02**:
Sorry, I must have confused you with the naming convention.  It's not in /usr it's in the home directory as you stated. It's just that the "whatever" is called "usr" in this case.